# Convert postgres timestamp (+ timezone) to Date object [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, postgresql, date, timestamp, momentjs

Our postgres database returns a string with a timestamp: `'2016-07-24T03:32:45.678Z'`

We are trying to use the `moment.js` library, but it only accepts a Date object.

How can I convert the above timestamp+timezone into a Date object using Javascript?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Moment accepts and in fact prefers strings. The best practice with moment is to never use a date object unless it has been given to you by a third party API. MOment should parse this time format by default when you pass it to the moment constructor.

Comment: See parsing strings: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use `moment(some_date).fromNow()`

Instead of `moment.startOf(some_date).fromNow()`

Answer (score 11):

```
new Date(dateString.replace(' ', 'T'));
```

Comment: some conversion of date is invalid.

Comment: @ManoharsinhRana: can you please clarify why this code would fail to convert some date strings / create an invalid conversion?

Perhaps the confusion is that the O.P. stated that they needed to have this function work with a PG Timestamps WITH timezone... when their example shows +0, which is how Postgres stores timestamps without timezones (UTC / Unix Compatible).

Thanks! Interested to hear your response!